Can I use the Gsr short-rate model in quantlib to find the OAS of callable bonds
I am trying to find the OAS of callable/puttable bonds using TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine. This works when I use the HullWhite or BlackKarasinski short-rate models, but they do not allow for time-varying volatility and mean-reversion. when I try using the Gsr short-rate model, I get this error:
TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
  TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine::TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine(ext::shared_ptr< ShortRateModel > const &,Size,Handle< YieldTermStructure > const &)
  TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine::TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine(ext::shared_ptr< ShortRateModel > const &,Size)
  TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine::TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine(ext::shared_ptr< ShortRateModel > const &,TimeGrid const &,Handle< YieldTermStructure > const &)
  TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine::TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine(ext::shared_ptr< ShortRateModel > const &,TimeGrid const &)

Does this mean that the Gsr model is not compatible with the TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine? Are there other methods to find the OAS of bonds with the Gsr model?
My Gsr model is calibrated and I am able to use it in the Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine. This is the code I am using:
import QuantLib as ql
import numpy as np

Set Up the Evaluation Environment
today = ql.Date(2, ql.October, 2024)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = today

Define the Yield Term Structure
flat_forward_rate = 0.02  # 2% flat rate
day_count = ql.Actual365Fixed()
calendar = ql.TARGET()
settlement_days = 2

spot_curve = ql.FlatForward(today, flat_forward_rate, day_count)
term_structure_handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(spot_curve)

Set Up Market Data for Swaptions
swaption_maturities = [ql.Period(i, ql.Years) for i in range(1, 6)]  # 1Y to 5Y
swap_tenors = [ql.Period(5, ql.Years)] * 5
market_vols = [0.20, 0.19, 0.18, 0.17, 0.16]

Create Swaption Helpers
swaption_helpers = []

fixed_leg_frequency = ql.Annual
fixed_leg_convention = ql.ModifiedFollowing
fixed_leg_daycount = ql.Thirty360(ql.Thirty360.BondBasis)
floating_leg_frequency = ql.Semiannual
floating_leg_convention = ql.ModifiedFollowing
floating_leg_daycount = ql.Actual360()
index = ql.Euribor6M(term_structure_handle)

for maturity, tenor, vol in zip(swaption_maturities, swap_tenors, market_vols):
    helper = ql.SwaptionHelper(
        maturity,
        tenor,
        ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(vol)),
        index,
        index.tenor(),
        fixed_leg_daycount,
        floating_leg_daycount,
        term_structure_handle
    )
    swaption_helpers.append(helper)

Initialize the GSR Model
vol_times = [today + m for m in swaption_maturities[:-2]]
initial_vols = [ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.01)) for _ in range(len(vol_times)+1)]
reversions = [ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.01))]
short_rate_model = ql.Gsr(term_structure_handle, vol_times, initial_vols, reversions)

Set Up the Swaption Pricing Engine
engine = ql.Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine(short_rate_model, 64, 7.0)
for helper in swaption_helpers:
    helper.setPricingEngine(engine)

Calibrate the GSR Model
optimization_method = ql.LevenbergMarquardt()
end_criteria = ql.EndCriteria(
    1000,    # maxIterations
    500,     # maxStationaryStateIterations
    1e-8,    # rootEpsilon
    1e-8,    # functionEpsilon
    1e-8     # gradientNormEpsilon
)
short_rate_model.calibrate(swaption_helpers, optimization_method, end_criteria)

steps=100
callable_bond_engine = ql.TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine(short_rate_model, steps)


Did you get a solution or a workaround. I too am looking for the above implementation. One way would be to setup the callable bond as a Non Standard Swap underlying with nominals of floating leg as zeros and encapsulate it in NonStandardSwaption. Implementation from line 284 in below link:
https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/blob/master/Python/examples/gaussian1d-models.py

I think that the example you're referring to is indeed the best way to do it. From how I understand it, this only allows for the use of time-varying volatility in the Gsr model. Do you know if it is possible to use other models with the NonStandardSwaption approach?
